# Unable to get list of connected external devices( USB, Hard drive) in macOS/Windows Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

Need to get list of HID Devices (External devices like USB pen drive / Hard disks) with info in Flutter window desktop app.

Already tried below plugins but still not getting list of connected external devices.

https://pub.dev/packages/hid

https://pub.dev/packages/quick_usb

https://pub.dev/packages/libusb

https://pub.dev/packages/device_manager

Answer (score 0):

You can use the manual way. Just run a terminal command to get all of it.

```
import 'dart:io';

somefunction() async {
  await Process.run("ioreg -p IOUSB"}).then((result) {
    print(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can we filter list of connected devices with - Only devices which has volume space?

Getting list of attached devices from below command.
ioreg -p IOUSB -w0 | sed 's/[^o]*o //; s/@.*$//' | grep -v '^Root.*'